# Storage for api request in cypress

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress

How can I store a request for an api get (a script type) in cypress and not have to wait for each test in the suite to load its data after that request? I sometimes lose up to 20 seconds waiting. Is there a storage option?

First I tried to ignore those api's with long load times, with `cy.intercept('api.link',{}).as('link')`, or similar methods, but I realized that's not a solution. I also don't think `cy.session()` is an option for this either.

I hope I have provided all the details, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are in the same spec file, you can store the value in a Cypress environment variable via `Cypress.env()`, or if they are in the same describe block, you can simply do the request in the `before` block.

```
// foo.spec.ts
describe('test', () => {
  
  let response;

  before(() => {
    cy.request('foo', (req) => {
      req.continue((res) => {
        // if using Cypress.env()
        Cypress.env('response', res);
        // if using a scoped variable
        response = res;
      });
    });

  });

  it('tests', () => {
    // something that uses either `Cypress.env('response')` or `response`.
  });
})
```

If you need this to run just once before the entire suite, you can include the call in your `plugins/index` file, and [use the `before:run` API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api#Syntax)

```js
// plugins/index.js
...
const axios = require('axios').default // using axios to query endpoint
...
on('before:run', async () => {
  await axios.get('foo').then((response) => {
    config.env.CYPRESS_MY_VAR = response
  })
});
...

// some.spec.ts
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    cy.log(Cypress.env('MY_VAR');
  });
});
```

So, what's happening in the above?

1. We're using [`axios` to fetch the data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). You can use any library or method to query the endpoint, Axios is just my preferred.
2. In the `.then()` callback, we're taking the response and assigning it to a Cypress variable. Because `Cypress.` and `cy.` commands are not available in the `plugins/index` file, we instead use `config.env.` to set the environment variable. Any variable prefixed with `CYPRESS_` is interpreted to be a custom environment variable. In this case, `CYPRESS_MY_VAR`
3. In the test, we're logging the value of `Cypress.env('MY_VAR')`. Note that this key is `MY_VAR` and not `CYPRESS_MY_VAR`.

Comment: Does this code structure have to be put in every test? I have a test folder with several spec files. I ask because I tried to put it at the beginning of a test and loading that api is done at the beginning, where time is lost anyway. Then if I call from another test that  Cypress.env('response'), it doesn't work.

Comment: `Cypress.env()` variables are only scoped to the spec file they are created in. So yes, you'd have to add this to each spec file. I did call this out in my initial explanation.

Comment: I don't think your version is the best for me. I say that because at the beginning of each test, cypress makes that request, waits for a few seconds for it (the same seconds as if it were inside the test) then runs the test and indeed when it has to jump that get, it does and that time is removed (but added to the beginning). I was thinking that with your version I was temporarily storing the result of that request in the 'response' variable, but it doesn't really work that way.

Comment: That's fair enough. I'll try to think on some other strategies. One immediate one that comes to mind would be to modify your `plugins/index.ts` to execute the call when the suite loads, but you'd have to use axios or another service to do the call, as `cy.` commands can't be run in that file.

Comment: If you have any other ideas that come to mind, I'd be happy to share them. I'd save ~10 seconds per test in that way.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured _something_ out. I'll edit my comment to include that.,

Comment: I have this error: "Your pluginsFile is invalid: ..\cypress\plugins\index.js

It threw an error when required, check the stack trace below:

ReferenceError: on is not defined" any idea why?

Comment: Do you have a configured Plugins File already? If not, you should set one up -> https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide#List-of-plugins

Comment: Yes, i've configured that. Maybe can i add this before that : "module.exports = (on, config) => {
" ?

Comment: The `on('before:run')` needs to be within the module.exports

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple cache and wrap it in a custom command

**cypress/support/index.js**

```js
let cachedResult = null;

Cypress.Commands.add('readAndCacheApi', async (url) => {
  if (!cachedResult) {
    console.log('fetching')
    const result = await fetch(url) 
    cachedResult = result
    return cachedResult
  } else {
    console.log('using cache')
    return cachedResult
  }
})
```

**Spec 1**

```js
it('test1', () => {
  cy.readAndCacheApi('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')  // logs "fetching"
    .then(data => {

    })

  cy.readAndCacheApi('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')  // logs "using cache"
    .then(data => {

    })
})

it('test2', () => {
  cy.readAndCacheApi('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')  // logs "using cache"
    .then(data => {

    })
})
```

**Spec 2, run with spec 1**

```js
it('test3', () => {
  cy.readAndCacheApi('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')  // logs "using cache"
    .then(data => {

    })
})
```

**Spec 2, run by itself**

```js
it('test3', () => {
  cy.readAndCacheApi('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')  // logs "fetching"
    .then(data => {

    })
})
```